# Finding original start date to absence period

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Could you please take a look at the following task?

I have **DATA** table (it contains data for **previous week**):

```
CREATE TABLE DATA
(
EMPLOYEE nvarchar(50),
ABSENCE_START_DATE datetime,
ABSENCE_END_DATE datetime,
ABSENCE_TYPE nvarchar(50)
)

ABSENCE_START_DATE - date when absence starts
ABSENCE_END_DATE  - date when absence ends
ABSENCE_TYPE - type of absence
```

Current table contains the following data:

```
INSERT INTO DATA(EMPLOYEE,ABSENCE_START_DATE,ABSENCE_END_DATE,ABSENCE_TYPE) VALUES
('EMP01','2017-09-04 00:00:00.000','2017-09-06 00:00:00.000','Sickness'),--Monday - Wednesday
('EMP01','2017-09-08 00:00:00.000','2017-09-08 00:00:00.000','Vacation'),--Friday - Friday
('EMP02','2017-09-04 00:00:00.000','2017-09-09 00:00:00.000','Sickness'),--Monday - Friday
('EMP03','2017-09-05 00:00:00.000','2017-09-09 00:00:00.000','Sickness')--Tuesday - Friday
```

[image]

Also, I have another table - **STORAGE** (it contains data for dates which are earlier than start of previous week).

```
CREATE TABLE STORAGE
(
EMPLOYEE nvarchar(50),
APPLY_DATE datetime,
ABSENCE_TYPE nvarchar(50)
)
```

There are daily records (excluding Saturdays and Sundays - they will never exist in this table)

```
INSERT INTO STORAGE(EMPLOYEE,APPLY_DATE,ABSENCE_TYPE) VALUES
('EMP01','2017-08-27 00:00:00.000','Sickness'),
('EMP01','2017-08-28 00:00:00.000','Worked'),
('EMP01','2017-08-29 00:00:00.000','Worked'),
('EMP01','2017-08-30 00:00:00.000','Sickness'),
('EMP01','2017-08-31 00:00:00.000','Sickness'),
('EMP01','2017-09-01 00:00:00.000','Sickness'),
('EMP02','2017-08-31 00:00:00.000','Worked'),
('EMP02','2017-09-01 00:00:00.000','Sickness')
```

[image]

**So, the task is**: 
sql -script should find original start date to absence periods (from DATA table) which absence start date is **Monday**.

In other words, script should go day after day "in the past" and find date when appropriate absence period starts.

Not necessary that absence on Monday is 'Sickness'. It could be also 'Travel','Maternity'...

Expected result for examples below is (pay attention to first and third rows - absence start dates are different from appropriate rows in DATA table):

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: in STORAGE, EMP01 worked on 2017-08-29, but your expected result shows this as the start of their absence. Is that right?

Comment: why is `absence_start_date = 2017-08-29` in result for `emp01` as according to `storage` table he worked on the same date? In case of `emp03` its correct? or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, sorry guys you are right. My fault

Comment: I modified 'Expected' result section screen below

Answer (score 0):

From the sample data shared, it seems that you are looking to retrieve `min` `date` from `storage` to `absence_start_date` column of `data` table, below query can be an option.

```
SELECT d.Employee,
       coalesce(CASE
                    WHEN d.ABSENCE_TYPE = 'Sickness' THEN
                           (SELECT min(apply_date)
                            FROM
                            STORAGE s
                            WHERE s.employee = d.employee
                              AND s.ABSENCE_TYPE = 'Sickness')
                    ELSE d.ABSENCE_START_DATE
                END,d.ABSENCE_START_DATE) AS ABSENCE_START_DATE,
       d.ABSENCE_END_DATE,
       ABSENCE_TYPE
FROM DATA d;
```

**Update 1:**
A more generic query is below.

```
SELECT d.Employee,
       coalesce(
                  (SELECT min(apply_date)
                   FROM
                   STORAGE s
                   WHERE s.employee = d.employee
                     AND s.ABSENCE_TYPE = d.ABSENCE_TYPE),d.ABSENCE_START_DATE) AS ABSENCE_START_DATE,
       d.ABSENCE_END_DATE,
       d.ABSENCE_TYPE
FROM DATA d
```

**Update 2:**
If you want to exclude `weekends` from the data, below is the query.

```
SELECT d.Employee,
       coalesce(
                  (SELECT min(apply_date)
                   FROM
                   STORAGE s
                   WHERE s.employee = d.employee
                     AND s.ABSENCE_TYPE = d.ABSENCE_TYPE
                     AND DATENAME(dw,apply_date) NOT IN('Sunday','Saturday')),d.ABSENCE_START_DATE) AS ABSENCE_START_DATE,
       d.ABSENCE_END_DATE,
       d.ABSENCE_TYPE
FROM DATA d
```

**Result:**

```
Employee    ABSENCE_START_DATE      ABSENCE_END_DATE    ABSENCE_TYPE
--------------------------------------------------------------------
EMP01       30.08.2017 00:00:00    06.09.2017 00:00:00    Sickness
EMP01       08.09.2017 00:00:00    08.09.2017 00:00:00    Vacation
EMP02       01.09.2017 00:00:00    09.09.2017 00:00:00    Sickness
EMP03       05.09.2017 00:00:00    09.09.2017 00:00:00    Sickness
```

you can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/ZMNLBA89961)**

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Zarruq, thank you a lot. Yes, it works, but in your code you have the following filter "ABSENCE_TYPE = 'Sickness' ", but it could be possible to have another absence types on Monday. E.g. 'Travel', 'Maternity'...So, in that case code will not work.

Comment: Zarruq, I do not need to find min date from storage  to  absence_start_date column of data table. E.g. in Storage employee EMP01 has the following data:
EMP01  2017-08-28 Sickness
EMP01  2017-08-29 Worked
EMP01  2017-08-30 Sickness
EMP01  2017-08-31 Sickness

So, your code will find August, 28th as start of absence, but it need to be 30th of August

Comment: @DavidFreeman: Update your question. i will update my answer. I assume on the limited data provided. On your current sample data, my query works.

Comment: @DavidFreeman: Check updated answer. I have added a more generic query.

Comment: Zarruq, if STORAGE contains the following data:

EMP01 2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 Sickness
EMP01 2017-08-28 00:00:00.000 Worked
EMP01 2017-08-29 00:00:00.000 Worked
EMP01 2017-08-30 00:00:00.000 Sickness
EMP01 2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 Sickness
EMP01 2017-09-01 00:00:00.000 Sickness

Comment: Your code updated code will return the followng data for EMP01:
EMP01 2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 2017-09-06 00:00:00.000 Sickness
EMP01 2017-09-08 00:00:00.000 2017-09-08 00:00:00.000 Vacation

which is incorrect.

Expected result should be:

EMP01 2017-08-30 00:00:00.000 2017-09-06 00:00:00.000 Sickness
EMP01 2017-09-08 00:00:00.000 2017-09-08 00:00:00.000 Vacation

Comment: Dude, I think you need to go through [how to ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056) first :-)

Comment: OK, sorry for wasting your time :(

Comment: Yes, STORAGE table will never contain data for Saturdays and Sundays.

Comment: @DavidFreeman: Check the update 2 query. demo has also been updated.

Comment: you are genius :) Many thanks! Main test are passed, I will close question when all my tests will pass.

Comment: unfortunately script does not work when EMP01 'Worked' on '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000'. In this case, ABSENCE_START_DATE should not be changed in DATA table. It should be '2017-09-04 00:00:00.000' as previously

Comment: @DavidFreeman: I would recommend you to do your homework, come up with all possible scenarios, share it in a new question and close this question. We will help you in a better way then :-)